# Why i am not able to parse a simple Expression using javacc tool

Tags: java, compiler-construction, javacc

I am a beginner in using a tool and I have made a class `Expression.jj` in which i have used the following grammar

```
expr->expr+term|term
term->term*fact|fact
fact->(expr)|num
```

Here is the Source Code

```
PARSER_BEGIN(Expression)

public class Expression
{
   public static void main(String s[])
   {
     try
     {
        new Expression(new java.io.StringReader(args[0])).StartSymbol();
        System.out.println("Syntex checking successfull");
     }
     catch(Throwable e) 
     {
        System.out.println("Syntex checking failed");   
        e.getMessage();
     }
  }
}

PARSER_END(Expression)

SKIP:{"" | "\t" | "\n" | "\r" }

TOKEN:{"(" | ")" | "+" | "*" |<NUM: (["0"-"9"])+>}

void StartSymbol():
{
    (Expr())*
    <EOF>
}

void Expr():
{
    Term() ("+" Term())*
}

void Term():
{
    Factor() ("*" Factor())*
}

void Factor():
{
  <NUM> | "(" Expr() ")"
}
```

OutputShown in cmd

```
C:\>java -cp C:\javacc5.0\javacc-5.0\bin\lib\javacc.jar javacc 
C:\compilerprog\Expression.jj Java Compiler Compiler Version 5.0 (Parser Generator)
(type "javacc" with no arguments for help)
Reading from file C:\compilerprog\Expression.jj . . .
Error: Could not open file Expression.java for writing.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error
        at org.javacc.parser.ParseGen.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.javacc.parser.Main.mainProgram(Unknown Source)
        at org.javacc.parser.Main.main(Unknown Source)
        at javacc.main(Unknown Source)
```

@EDIT

It's running when i am using this command:

```
C:\javaccprog>java -cp C:\javacc5.0\javacc-5.0\bin\lib\javacc.jar javacc Expression.jj
```

instead of:

```
C:\java -cp C:\javacc5.0\javacc-5.0\bin\lib\javacc.jar javacc C:\compilerprog\Expression.jj
```

Comment: Please reformat this illegible mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Error: Could not open file Expression.java for writing.` means that you can not write to 'Expression.java', please change your working directory.

Comment: i don't have a java file there How is that possible?Still the same error even after changing.

Comment: also i have a single drive for windows and other drive is for mac.So it didn't have permission there.

Comment: maybe you shouldn't run `java` in `C:\ `, because in new Windows Systems, you cannot write file to `C:\ ` with a normal user privilege.